# How to use mapping overrides from many assemblies within FluentNhibernate AutoPersistenceModel generator

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Is it possible to configure the autopersistence model to read mapping and mapping overrides from many assemblies.

At the moment I use

```
public AutoPersistenceModel Generate()
        {
            var model =
                new AutoPersistenceModel()
                    .AddEntityAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(User)))
                    .Where(
                    this.GetAutoMappingFilter).Conventions.Setup(this.GetConventions()).Setup(this.GetSetup()).

                    UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<AutoPersistenceModelGenerator>();

            return model;
        }

        public AutoPersistenceModel Generate(params Assembly[] assemblies)
        {
            var model = this.Generate();
            assemblies.ToList().ForEach(x => model.AddEntityAssembly(x));

            return model;
        }
```

The problem is with

```
  UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<AutoPersistenceModelGenerator>();
```

which takes only one assembly. BUt I would like to collect mapping and their otherrides from different assemblies.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We took a slightly different approach to solving this problem using the 1.3.x version of FNH, with a few specific design goals in mind:

- Keep our domain entities POCO.
- Take advantage of the FNH auto-persistence mechanism.
- Package IAutoMappingOverride instances in the assembly with the entities on which they depend.
- Allow the "plug-in" of new assemblies containing mapped entities without having to alter the core FNH configuration.

Much like the OP's solution, all of our mapped entities inherit from a set of well-known base classes. Armed with this and the fact that AutoPersistenceModel.UseOverridesFromAssembly() can indeed be called multiple times, we were able to make a simple modification to our auto-mapping configuration class to dynamically add the override assemblies:

```
internal sealed class SessionConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public AutoPersistenceModel PersistenceModel
    {
        get
        {
            Assembly[] assembliesToMap = MappedAssemblyResolver.GetMappedAssemblies();
            AutoPersistenceModel model = AutoMap.Assemblies(new SessionConfiguration(), assembliesToMap);

            foreach (Assembly potentiallyMapped in MappedAssemblyResolver.GetOverrideAssemblies(assembliesToMap))
            {
                model.UseOverridesFromAssembly(potentiallyMapped);
            }

            model.Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<SessionConfiguration>();
            // other FNH configuration options omitted

            return model;
        }
    }

    public override bool ShouldMap(Type type)
    {
        return type.IsSubclassOfRawGeneric(typeof(DomainObject<>));
    }
}
```

MappedAssemblyResolver looks something like this:

```
internal static class MappedAssemblyResolver
{
    public static Assembly[] GetMappedAssemblies()
    {
        Assembly[] mappedAssemblies; 
        // TODO: implement your strategy for resolving assemblies

        return mappedAssemblies;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Assembly> GetOverrideAssemblies(Assembly[] mappedAssemblies)
    {
        mappedAssemblies.CheckNull("mappedAssemblies");

        return mappedAssemblies;
    }
}
```

A few items of note:

1. DomainObject is our base domain entity. It contains common things like Id, DateCreated, etc.
2. IsSubclassOfRawGeneric(Type) is an extension method, available [here](https://gist.github.com/3289331).
3. CheckNullOrEmpty(string) is an extension method, available [here](https://gist.github.com/3403869).
4. You'll need to implement a way of actually resolving your assemblies in GetMappedAssemblies(). We do some inspection of AppDomain.CurrentDomain and them apply some rules to determine which assemblies we consider to be matches.

Also note that, while we're putting the IAutoMappingOverride instances in the same assembly as our entities, you could easily change the implementation of GetOverrideAssemblies(Assembly[]) if your goal was to further decouple your domain from FNH.

Either way, this should allow you to add new mapped entities (or new assemblies containing them) and their related mapping overrides at will without giving much thought to their addition to the underlying FNH AutoPersistenceModel.

Comment: thanks, First look at this idea looks fine for me. Just need to check the impact of the refactoring to this, shouldn't be to much.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem with .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf is that they do not duplicate type.

Code snipped from FluentNHibernate:

```
public AutoPersistenceModel UseOverridesFromAssembly(Assembly assembly)
    {
      this.alterations.Add(new AutoMappingOverrideAlteration(assembly));
      return this;
    }
public AutoMappingAlterationCollection Add(IAutoMappingAlteration alteration)
    {
      if (!this.alterations.Exists(a => a.GetType() == alteration.GetType()))
      {
        this.alterations.Add(alteration);
      }
      return this;
    }
```

You can see that adding duplicate type is not allowed.

After investigation FNH code I found that they finally alter the AutoMappingOverrideAlteration and I just write an extension to apply this altering

```
 public static class AutoPersistenceModelExtension
    {
        public static AutoPersistenceModel AddMappingAssembly(this AutoPersistenceModel model, Assembly assembly)
        {
            new AutoMappingOverrideAlteration(assembly).Alter(model);
            return model;
        }

        public static AutoPersistenceModel AddMappingFromAssemblyOf<T>(this AutoPersistenceModel model)
        {
            return model.AddEntityAssembly(typeof (T).Assembly);
        }


    }
```

The result is:
Our application is build based on components, each components provide own Entities and Mappings for those entities. Each component should be derived from a BaseComponent class which has an abstract method to Alter the model.

Ex of FulfillmentModuleRegistration:

```
public override void AddToModel(AutoPersistenceModel autoPersistenceModel)
        {
            autoPersistenceModel.AddEntityAssembly(typeof(SupplierListItem).Assembly);
            autoPersistenceModel.AddMappingFromAssemblyOf<SupplierListItemMappingOverride>();
        }
```

and our global.asax.cs:

```
 var autoPersistenceModel = new AutoPersistenceModelGenerator().Generate();
            //TODO: Refactor this, instead of instantiate each module we have to go thought a list of loaded module and apply their model alteration
            new QuestionBankModuleRegistration().AddToModel(autoPersistenceModel);
            new FulfilmentServiceAreaRegistration().AddToModel(autoPersistenceModel);

            var cfg = NHibernateSession.Init(
                this.webSessionStorage,
                new[] { this.Server.MapPath("~/bin/baseMappings.dll") },
                autoPersistenceModel,
                this.Server.MapPath("~/Hibernate.cfg.xml"));
```

baseMappings.dll contains our base entities like : Users, Lookups, etc. So it could be any assembly which contains base, default mappings, conventions, etc.